# How to follow seaborn's examples

Tags: python, dataset, seaborn

Every official seaborn demo/example begins with `sns.load_dataset()`. I'm wondering where I can get those seaborn dataset so that I can follow the examples?

I tried to find them myself using phrases like *"where to find official seaborn dataset"* etc, etc but got no hits.

**UPDATE:**

So, how can I use them? I'm following http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html, and [this is the only thing that I get](https://gist.github.com/suntong/830ad1992b983fae5410), i.e., I don't get any charts.

Both of my seaborn and pandas are working fine though. They are from my Anaconda installation, and are all of the latest versions. The version of matplotlib that I'm using [works fine with seaborn as well](https://gist.github.com/suntong/fab7d054823b8d42385a).

@gabra, I've found those csv files from the internet before asking the question, because I think they are just csv files, and can't be directly used in `sns.load_dataset(xxx)`, right?

Comment: The data sets are installed together with `seaborn`. Do you want to know where they are in your computer?

Comment: It appears that the version of matplotlib that you are using is too new and not compatible with the version of seaborn. I would look into using an older version of matplotlib.

Comment: Specifically, Try either matplotlib 1.3.1 because it was published in Oct - 2013 and the seaborn package was developed 2 years ago. Or, there are a lot of commits to the seaborn package in the last 5 months, and that might be in response to matplotlib 1.4.3 which was published in Feb 2015. I would try both.

Comment: What are your `matplotlib` and `seaborn` versions?

Comment: Hey, please refrain from changing the question with edits. If you need more detail from answers, please comment on the specific answer. If you have a new question, please use the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button to ask a new question, and link to this question for reference.

Comment: Hey, please respect other's work and discussion. Can't you see that the main question *never changed*, but only *more details are provided*? What would it hurt to add more details? Why do you remove those added details, especially when those details are clarifying people's answers/questions? Show some respect.

Comment: Different people have different ways doing thing, please don't force your own way to others.  Wouldn't it be bad idea to spread the question all over the places to follow up here and there? How could another new person who come along figure out what I'm asking if s/he has to hunt all over the places trying to figure out what I'm asking? Wouldn't it be much clearer to have the question reside in *one central place*? I repeat, **the main question never changed**, and you can see that yourself from the history. It has always been the SAME question!

Comment: _"Different people have different ways doing thing, please don't force your own way to others."_ And this site has a standard of quality. You've asked an additional question after your first question was answered, and this caused the answer to your question to be different, as can be seen by the edit to the accepted answer. This is not what we want from users on Stack Overflow. Madara is a moderator on the site, and it only enforcing the guidelines of the site. If you have a new question, ask it separately please. Do not change your question wanting new, or different, answers.

Comment: This is getting crazy. *"Do not change your question wanting new, or different, answers"* Are we discussing hypothetical situations or this one partially? **If discussing hypothetical situations, I totally agree with you.** , but if we are discussing this one partial situation, please take a look at the history before take sides. let me repeat, the main question never changed, only more details are provided. I'm still asking the same question and wanting the same answer.

Comment: @xpt It may not feel that way to you, who wrote the question, but to most others it does seem like a major change. Or rather, if you meant "I have a problem with the chart-generating examples, please help" from the beginning, then your writing "...so that I can follow the examples" didn't quite communicate it. The readers' focus was on the more specific "where I can get those seaborn dataset". The rest deserves a new question, which I'd be interested in as I have a similar problem. New to seaborn, too.[edit] Oh eff this question is old. Hate those fancy date formats.

Comment: @kaay, finally found someone who is facing the same problem as me. All that I got before was down-voting. :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data sets are located in another repository, called [seaborn-data](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/).

In this repo, each data set is stored as a `.csv` file.

#### Update

Try this:

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline # To show embedded plots in the notebook

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.boxplot(tips["total_bill"])
```

Comment: @DanLowe, thanks for your feedback. I updated it and I hope it is better.

Answer (score 0):

The seaborn package should include either the sample datasets cited within the example tutorial or the methods for retrieving the dataset.

```
# Load the example planets dataset
planets = sns.load_dataset("planets")
```

When I look for the "planets" dataset within the [example folder](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/tree/master/examples), I don't see the datasets.  A litte exploration of the function "load_datasets" reveals that the example datasets are coming from the [seaborn-data file](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/) online and require the pandas package dependency.

```
def load_dataset(name, cache=True, data_home=None, **kws):
    """Load a dataset from the online repository (requires internet).
    Parameters
    ----------
    name : str
        Name of the dataset (`name`.csv on
        https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data).  You can obtain list of
        available datasets using :func:`get_dataset_names`
    cache : boolean, optional
        If True, then cache data locally and use the cache on subsequent calls
    data_home : string, optional
        The directory in which to cache data. By default, uses ~/seaborn_data/
    kws : dict, optional
        Passed to pandas.read_csv
    """
    path = "https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/raw/master/{0}.csv"
    full_path = path.format(name)

    if cache:
        cache_path = os.path.join(get_data_home(data_home),
                                  os.path.basename(full_path))
        if not os.path.exists(cache_path):
            urlretrieve(full_path, cache_path)
        full_path = cache_path

    df = pd.read_csv(full_path, **kws)
    if df.iloc[-1].isnull().all():
        df = df.iloc[:-1]

    if not pandas_has_categoricals:
        return df

    # Set some columns as a categorical type with ordered levels

    if name == "tips":
        df["day"] = pd.Categorical(df["day"], ["Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"])
        df["sex"] = pd.Categorical(df["sex"], ["Male", "Female"])
        df["time"] = pd.Categorical(df["time"], ["Lunch", "Dinner"])
        df["smoker"] = pd.Categorical(df["smoker"], ["Yes", "No"])

    if name == "flights":
        df["month"] = pd.Categorical(df["month"], df.month.unique())

    if name == "exercise":
        df["time"] = pd.Categorical(df["time"], ["1 min", "15 min", "30 min"])
        df["kind"] = pd.Categorical(df["kind"], ["rest", "walking", "running"])
        df["diet"] = pd.Categorical(df["diet"], ["no fat", "low fat"])

    if name == "titanic":
        df["class"] = pd.Categorical(df["class"], ["First", "Second", "Third"])
        df["deck"] = pd.Categorical(df["deck"], list("ABCDEFG"))

    return df
```

Comment: It appears that the version of matplotlib that you are using is too new and not compatible with the version of seaborn.  I would look into using an older version of matplotlib.

Comment: Hmm? My updated question should show that I'm still quite confused and lost.

Comment: Can you please run "print matplotlib.__version__" and let us know what version of matplotlib you have on your machine?

Comment: Also, you should probably select an answer, close this question, and open a new question.  Your question has changed from where is this data to what version of matplotlib is compatible with seaborn.  We have answered the original question, and are not getting reputation points for it because you have expanded into a different more time consuming question.

Comment: Dude, I said my version of matplotlib **is** compatible with seaborn, and I said I **can't use** those .csv files.